# How to set user dictionary in Visual Studio Spell Checker?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

How can I set the location of a user dictionary in in Visual Studio Add-In Tool "Visual Studio Spell Checker"?

Background: I want to use a user dictionary in my solution folder, which I can set under version control. Usually user dictionaries are stored under 
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\EWSoftware\Visual Studio Spell Checker

Answer (score 4):

User dictionaries can be added to solutions and projects and checked into source control so that they are local to each project. To do this:

1. Add a solution, project, folder, or file-specific spell checker configuration file based on how you want the dictionaries to be made available and used. (Select the solution, a project, a folder, or a file in the Solution Explorer window and use the **File | New | Spell Checker Configuration File for Selected Item** option to add a configuration for the selected item.)
2. In the configuration file, add the folder location to your solution
   user dictionary (copy the global user dictionary from
   *C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\EWSoftware\Visual Studio Spell
   Checker\en-US_User.dic* to your solution) to the Additional
   Dictionary Folders list in the Dictionary Settings category. When
   prompted, make the path relative to the configuration file so that
   the dictionary files can be found if the project is moved.

This should work for you.

Comment: Why would I want a per-project language? is there no way to set this globally for all projects?

Comment: @Matt, if using git, place the dictionary in a shared repository which all projects reference. Analogous to [this shared .editorconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186841/editorconfig-in-shared-git-repository/52189274#52189274)